# Using Eclipse IDE on multiple devices

Tags: eclipse, drive

For starters, I use multiple computers, and sometimes, I use certain computers for once, and never again. This is something that I cannot fix. In such a case, I cannot go on downloading Eclipse IDE for work on every computer and then just leave it.

I tried installing Eclipse on a pendrive, and then using it for multiple computers, but it didn't work. As usual, eclipse.ini was the culprit. It contained paths from the computer I first downloaded Eclipse from, and that was the cause it didnt work in other computers. This error message showed up in other computers: `The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.`

Is there any way I can make eclipse entirely local to an external hard drive or pendrive for use on multiple PCs???

This is my eclipse.ini file:

```
startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.300.v20210813-1054.jar
--launcher.library
C:/Users/pedne/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.300.v20210828-0802
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\pedne\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.21.0.20210910-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Users/pedne/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.0.v20211012-1059/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The only local references are in the C:\ drive at lines 4,8, and 13. Manually changing the paths for every computer isnt possible as I maybe using eclipse for the first time on multiple computers.

Any help, links to other answers, or moderation will be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks like you used the Oomph installer which puts things in the .p2 directory. Try using one of the package installs from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ which don't use that location.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I do use the Oomph installer every time, and it doesnt allow installation to an external drive. That was a part of the problem. Anyway, Your solution worked like a charm. If you could just post this as an answer, that will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .p2 directory is the location used by the Oomph installer style of Eclipse install.

Using the package style install from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ will put everything in the Eclipse directory.

Note that this is still specific to a particular operating system. You can't have a single install for all operating systems.

Comment: The OS Problem is all right, I usually work on windows PCs only, but an install of all MacOS, Linux and Windows versions helps.